# How can I repeat a top level thead on subsequent pages with MPDF in PHP?

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm having trouble repeating multiple headers if needed on subsequent pages.

I've been trying for a while to find a solution with MPDF to repeat a top level thead on subsequent pages, for now.

On the screenshot, this is represented by the line highlighted in red on the first page, and I wish it was also on the second page where there is also a red rectangle.

At the moment, the very first row is in a table element apart from the others.

My difficulty is that I can generate a table that contains level 1 headers followed by a level 2 header, then content rows, then a level 2 header, then content rows...

I would like the level 1 header to be repeated on every page, but since it's in a separate table element, logically it doesn't.

But since it's not possible to have multiple thead elements in a table element, I have no choice but to put each thead element in its own table to repeat on the next page if needed. This works well with level 2 header elements, but since the level header is in an outside table element it logically doesn't work.

Here is a sample code to illustrate but does not work with Mpdf :
(I have the error : Notice: Undefined offset: 2)

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header1">FIRST</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header2">SECOND</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="header2">THREE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>DATA</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>END</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Have you ever encountered this scenario?
Do you have any clues to resolve this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

A `thead` element can be present only once in a HTML table and it must be placed before `tbody`:

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>
> As a child of a table element, after any caption, and colgroup elements and before any tbody, tfoot, and tr elements, but only if
> there are no other thead elements that are children of the table
> element.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-thead-element

The `thead` can contain multiple `tr` rows and is repeated on subsequent pages automatically by mPDF.

You can and probably should create "subtheads" by specific styling of `th` elements (or their parent row) inside a `tbody`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply.

My problem, i need place multiple thead style after and before multiple tbody on same table for repeat of thead work.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand what are you trying to say. Anyway, mPDF will repeat thead on subsequent pages only with a single thead element in the table.